# Memory corruption when traversing a file system

Tags: c, ubuntu, directory, filesystems

I am making a function that transverses all the sub files of a system and if it is a regular file prints out the file directory. It will print out a file if it is in the directory but once it tries to transverse a subdirectory it gives me a `malloc() memory corruption error` despite the fact that I am not mallocing anything.

```
void Traverse(char* dir)
{
    struct stat buffer;
    struct stat *s=&buffer;
    struct dirent* file;
    DIR* currentDir;
    // printf("%s \n",dir);
    if((strstr(dir,"./")!=NULL)||(strstr(dir,"../")!=NULL))
    return;
    currentDir = opendir(dir);
    if (lstat(dir,s)==0)
    {

        if(S_ISREG(s->st_mode))
        printf("%s \n", dir);

        else if (S_ISDIR (s->st_mode))
        {
            while((file= readdir(currentDir))!=NULL)
            {
                char* path = strdup(dir);
                strcat(path,"/");
                strcat(path,file->d_name);
                Traverse(path);
            }
            closedir(currentDir);
        }
    }
    else
    return;
}
```

Comment: I think the strcat might create an issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `strcat` into a `strdup`-ed memory (which is the same as `malloc`-ed memory), without allocating enough space for the suffix.

To fix this problem, you need to use `malloc`+`strcpy` (or some other way of forming a string, e.g. `sprintf`) instead of `strcat`, and make sure that you allocate additional space to your string. In addition, you need to call `free` to avoid memory leaks:

```
size_t len = strlen(dir)+strlen(file->d_name)+2; // 1 for '/' + 1 for '\0' => 2
char* path = malloc(len);
// Check the result of malloc here
sprintf(path, "%s/%s", dir, file->d_name);
Traverse(path);
free(path); // Avoid memory leaks
```